# npm not recognised after installing Heroku Toolbelt

Tags: npm, heroku-toolbelt

I've installed Heroku Toolbelt (https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) on a Windows 7 system.

I've followed the tutorial up to here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies

When I run the command `npm install` it gives the following error:

*'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

I understand this means it can't find/execute npm. But this is going from Heroku's own tutorial/documentation, in sequence, and doesn't say you need to install anything else to get this working. When I go to the npm website (https://www.npmjs.com/) it also says:

*The npm command-line tool is bundled with Node.js. If you have it installed, then you already have npm too.*

Something is wrong with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall nodejs. Alternatively, you can install nvm for windows, which is a version manager for nodejs. It's pretty useful and easy to install. Check it out at https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows